# Regular, intermittent loss of internet access. Network Manager seems to blame

Tags: networking, internet

Every so many minutes (ranges from 5-30) I lose internet connectivity. It seems to coincide with the following journalctl entry:

```
manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
```

Restarting NM temporarily repairs the connectivity and is reflected in journalctl:

```
manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
```

Sometimes NM repairs itself, but then breaks soon after, as shown by the following journalctl entries, which are the only log of this problem I have found so far.

```
    Nov 01 11:55:16 acer-Aspire-E5-575 NetworkManager[897]: <info>  [1667318116.4230] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
Nov 01 11:35:10 acer-Aspire-E5-575 NetworkManager[897]: <info>  [1667316910.1286] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Nov 01 11:35:10 acer-Aspire-E5-575 NetworkManager[897]: <info>  [1667316910.0496] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
Nov 01 11:29:51 acer-Aspire-E5-575 NetworkManager[897]: <info>  [1667316591.1179] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Nov 01 11:29:49 acer-Aspire-E5-575 NetworkManager[897]: <info>  [1667316589.0502] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
Nov 01 10:54:29 acer-Aspire-E5-575 NetworkManager[897]: <info>  [1667314469.1204] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Nov 01 10:54:28 acer-Aspire-E5-575 NetworkManager[897]: <info>  [1667314468.0475] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
Nov 01 10:29:09 acer-Aspire-E5-575 NetworkManager[897]: <info>  [1667312949.2071] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
```

I've already adjusted the powersave mode in /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf as described in related posts, but without success.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release: 22.04
Codename: jammy

Comment: Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`. Don't post logvomit ("here's my guess at all the data - you figure it out").
Do not post the whole log file! 99+% of the log entries are not of interest. Use an editor (on  a copy of the file), and keep ONLY the error entries, plus a few lines before and a few lines after. You should end up with a max of 50 lines, and probably fewer than 50. Edit your question to add information,  and use the formatting tools.

Comment: Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story. AskUbuntu is a Question and Answer site, not a conversation site. If you have an update, [edit] your Question.  If you have a new question, see  [Ask].